# useEffect cleanup not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

i want to clear event listener in react native. but the useEffect cleanup function not working for some reason.

my version

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

this is my code.

```
 useEffect(() => { 
 loadScreen();
 AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
  if (
    appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
    nextAppState === "active"
  ) {
    loadScreen();
  }

  appState.current = nextAppState;
  setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
  if(appState=='active'){
    var valuess = props.route.params.id.split("_");
    loadScreen();
  }
});

return () => {
  console.log("clean up works")
  AppState.removeEventListener("change", nextAppState=>{console.log("listener removed")});
};
  }, [props.route.params.id && appState=='active']);
```

the return function should work when i click the below button. the buttons works fine. it goes to cart screen

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>{ 
                props.navigation.navigate('Cart', { show_header: true ,referrel_code:props.Refferel,product_id:productDetails.id})
            
            }}
             
              style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
              <CartLink
                count={props.cart_data.items.length}
                amount={props.cart_data.subtotal}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

can use AppState.removeEventListener("change", nextAppState=>{console.log("listener removed")})  on when i press on the button instead of using in retrun?

Comment: What component is your effect in?  Are you sure it's getting unmounted? I can't tell because this isn't quite a [mcve].

Comment: @selbie its in referalScreen componenent, and there are multiple useEffects inside the component, so does multiple useEffect have anything to do with this?

Comment: You are using removeEventListener wrong. See [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener)

Comment: @Martin if i use remove, it shows undefined error, also i use older version of react native as on the question

Comment: You need to remove the same listener you registered earlier. This does nothing: `AppState.removeEventListener("change", nextAppState=>{console.log("listener removed")});`

Comment: @Martin yeah i tried that, i stored it in a subscription variable and used subscription.remove()

Comment: Yes. As I have said before. You are using `removeEventListener` wrong. Even if you have an old version that does not support the new `EventSubscription.remove()` method and you need to use the deprecated `removeEventListener`, you would still need to ensure that the callback you feed into `removeEventListener` is definitely the same callback instance that you fed into `addEventListener`.